# Calling user written code in Selenium IDE to generate values used in a test

Tags: selenium-ide, visualstudio

How can I call a user written function to generate and save a value into a parameter? I can use the `evalStore` command with some JavaScript as a parameter plus a variable name to hold the value. This is OK for simple bits of JavaScript but would be unwieldy for more complex functions.

How can I write code that can be invoked via a Selenium IDE command. My preference is to write the code in C# but other languages can be considered.

Simple example of where this is mechanism is needed: A test case requires tomorrow's date to be written, in a specific format, into a text field of a web page being tested. The ideal would be to enclose a C# call of `System.DateTime.Now.ToString("_the_format_wanted_")` in something that can be called from an IDE command.

Comment: Are you wanting to use the FireFox IDE and add C# code plug in to do this?

Comment: @JohnPeters Yes to Firefox IDE. A C# plugin would be good. My question was aiming to find what facilities are available and how to use them. I had not seen references to C# plugins for the IDE until now.